# Identify files under VC in Emacs Dired

Tags: git, svn, emacs, version-control

With a `.emacs` containing:

```
(global-font-lock-mode t)
(setq font-lock-maximum-decoration t)
```

I can easily identify files from directories (without looking at the 'd' flag).

I would like to identify files that are under version control from those that aren't.

After spending quite some time with SVN and git Emacs modes, I concluded (perhaps hastily) that they are not ready for prime-time, or at least basic things remain necessary to be done from the command line (and so it's easier to do everything from the command line), but this one is particularly pesky.

Can you suggest a lightweight method for distinguishing the files under VC?
(or, if not lightweight, provide a suitable `.emacs` config?)

Comment: I imagine that this question is not about Dired+, and you have the same question for vanilla Dired, i.e., for `emacs -Q`. If Dired+ is irrelevant here, you can simplify the description to not bring in library Dired+.

Comment: @Drew You're right. Dired suffices to distinguish files from directories, hence it may also be enough for VC flags. I haven't been able to keep up with the differences between dired, dired+, and dired-x. I have the impression that dired has grown gradually to compete with, and replace, dired-x and dired+. Is that the case? I suppose this merits a separate question. Comments are not a good place for this.

Comment: Vanilla Emacs has long (always?) had dired.el, dired-x.el, and dired-aux.el. Library dired+.el is not distributed with Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `diff-hl` package might be what you are looking for. It not only marks files that were changed, but also files that are not under VC control (in VC controlled directory).

Install it as usual (`M-x package-install RET diff-hl`) and then in init file:

```
(global-diff-hl-mode)     ; enables diff-hl for all buffers
(diff-hl-flydiff-mode)    ; diff-hl marks changes on the fly
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'diff-hl-dired-mode)  ; adds diff-hl for dired mode
```

You need also `fringe-mode` enabled to make it work, but I think Emacs comes with it preinstalled. You can use menu `Options` > `Show/Hide` > `Fringe` to check if fringe is set to something else than *None*.

Oh and when it comes to VC (at least Git) support, I find `magit` satisfactory. It's too complicated for my needs (and I still didn't figured out how to clone or init repo, so I use dired and execute git init or clone on `.` - current dir), but it's realiable and does it job.

Comment: Just fantastic! `diff-hl` does exactly what I was asking for, and much more. It silently and on the fly shows the code segments that have been added and the location where lines were deleted. As soon as I see the manual (it's not added to `C-h i`, so presumably I have to slog through the source), I'll determine whether there is a way to, say, hover over the lines that were deleted to see what was deleted or modified.